# Подключение через Laravel к БД - ошибка. Без Laravel - подключается

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Есть желание сделать использовать Laravel в качестве сервиса для Bitrix24. Соответственно, нужно подключить сервис к БД Битрикса.

На Laravel 8 работал костыль
require( app_path( "../../../bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php" ));

На Laravel 10 он не работает с какими-то ошибками psr, и это подтолкнуло меня к тому, что пора перестать использовать костыли.

```
*после каждых действий делаю 
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Прописываю в .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bazaDannyh
DB_USERNAME=userName
DB_PASSWORD="password5}([355g3r"
```

Получаю

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'userName'@'127.0.0.1'
> (using password: YES)

Меняю DB_HOST с 127.0.0.1 на localhost, получаю

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Добавляю 'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' - безрезультатно.

Возвращаюсь к 127.0.0.1, там очевидно есть коннект, но вход запрещен.

На абсолютно новой страничке проверяю, что логин пароль верный, что коннект к БД есть:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'userName', 'password5}([355g3r', 'bazaDannyh'); // ошибка "access denied"



$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'userName', 'password5}([355g3r', 'bazaDannyh'); // всё работает
```

Всё **работает**.
Соединение установлено... Localhost via UNIX socket

Значит причина в Laravel.
Отчаялся, заходу в config/database.php, удаляю из 'mysql' всё, в чём не уверен, даже для чистоты эксперемента напрямую указываю параметры, не используя env, остаётся

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'database' => 'bazaDannyh',
    'username' => 'userName',
    'password' => 'password5}([355g3r'
],
```

И снова SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'userName'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Если через localhost

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'bazaDannyh',
    'username' => 'userName',
    'password' => 'password5}([355g3r'
]
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Прошу помощи.
В инете нашёл, что что-то с сокетом.
Добавляю 'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' - вообще 0 эмоций.

Итогово усечённая версия должна быть по идее наподобие этого, но не работает.. Что-то с путём до unix сокета скорее всего?

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'bazaDannyh',
    'username' => 'userName',
    'password' => 'password5}([355g3r'
]
```

Comment: В `config/database.php` попробуйте создать новый блок `'mysql' => [` с другим названием) после чего подключайтесь к нему как `\DB::connection('sql2')->select`... настройки env и тд соответственно продублируйте на нужные данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.

1. Порт стандартный 3306 по неведомой причине сразу идёт в отказ. Заменил на 33060
2. Добавил 'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
3. php artisan optimize:clear
4. php artisan optimize
5. php artisan route:clear